# Is Xaml Style Sheet Inheritance Working in MAUI

Tags: maui

I am trying to get Style inheritance to work in my MAUI app by following this documentation for Xaml:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/inheritance.  So I have some simplified code that looks like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="EntryInput">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LabelColorDark}, Dark={StaticResource LabelColorDark}}" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource HintText}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Editor" x:Key="TextMultiLine" BasedOn="{StaticResource EntryInput}">
    </Style>
```

When I try running the app, it stops at launch time with an exception (details below).  If I remove the "BasedOn" attribute and just copy all the Setter elements from "EntryInput" and paste them into "TextMultiLine", the app runs fine and all the styles are correctly applied.  So is this not working now, or does it work different in MAUI, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's the exception info I get when using the BasedOn attribute; this is targeting an iPhone with iOS 15.5, using the GA of MAUI:

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException
Message=Position 7:29. Type converter failed: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue(Object xamlelement, XmlName propertyName, Object value, Object rootElement, INode node, HydrationContext context, IXmlLineInfo lineInfo)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit(ValueNode node, INode parentNode)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.FillResourceDictionariesVisitor.Visit(ValueNode node, INode parentNode)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.RootNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit(RootNode rootnode, HydrationContext visitorContext, Boolean useDesignProperties)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Assembly rootAssembly, Boolean useDesignProperties)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Boolean useDesignProperties)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, Type callingType)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[App](App view, Type callingType)
at MauiSteveApp.App.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\speschka\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\MauiSteve\MauiSteveApp\MauiSteveApp\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen.CodeBehindGenerator\App.xaml.sg.cs:line 22
at MauiSteveApp.App..ctor() in C:\Users\speschka\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\MauiSteve\MauiSteveApp\MauiSteveApp\App.xaml.cs:line 19
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Boolean wrapExceptions)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.DoInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[[System.Type, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Func`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].GetOrAdd(Type key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[IApplication](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass)
at MauiSteveApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\speschka\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\MauiSteve\MauiSteveApp\MauiSteveApp\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:line 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only inherit style that has **the same TargetType, or a "base class" TargetType** (that has the desired properties).

Given:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="EntryInput"> ...

<Style TargetType="View" x:Key="BaseView"> ...
    **<!-- IMPORTANT: Can ONLY use properties that exist in "View" class here -->**
```

These will work:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="TextMultiLine" BasedOn="{StaticResource EntryInput}"> ...

<Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="TextMultiLine" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseView}"> ...

<Style TargetType="Editor" x:Key="TextMultiLine" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseView}"> ...
```

This won't work:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Editor" x:Key="TextMultiLine" BasedOn="{StaticResource EntryInput}"> ...
```

Therefore, you'll have to make a new "Base" Style, either of "Editor", or of a base class of "Editor" (that has the desired properties defined in it).

Comment: Hmm. In the document I linked to above, it shows different target types (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/…). The base type it targets is "View". Can I use that in the same manner, and then base my other styles that target different types on it? Meaning, is "View" some type of base type that the other controls derive from and so that will work?

Comment: Right. I didn't remember that. Updated answer. NOTE: the "base" one has to be a class **That contains the desired properties**.